# Redirect in my htaccess causing 503 Server Too Busy

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been getting a bunch of 503's on my server and can't figure out why. Seems to be redirect related as my error log is bloated with errors like these:

```
[Fri Aug 15 09:27:09 2014] [error] [client xx.xxx.x.xxx] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Fri Aug 15 09:27:09 2014] [debug] core.c(3072): [client xx.xxx.x.xxx] r->uri = /wp/wp/wp/wp/wp/wp/wp/wp/wp/wp/login.php
```

Here are the contents of my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]

Include includes/ul-rewrites.txt

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*\.xxx\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(search|newsroom|aboutul|offerings|blog|es|fr).*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.xxx.com/$1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The offending line in your .htaccess is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
```

The server receives a request for `/login.php` and rewrites it to `/wp/login.php` and then rewrites it again to `/wp/wp/login.php` etc etc etc

Adding a rewrite condition to exclude requests that already correctly have /wp/ should resolve this. For instance:

```
RewriteCondition %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
```